# Automaticaly set value of attribute model activerecord without callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Ruby on Rails V5.

I have following model Trigger

```
class Trigger < ApplicationRecord
  
  attribute :run_at
  attribute :local_run_at, :time_only

end
```

When user will be update trigger with new value run_at, attribute local_run_at

If trigger was created or updated attribute local_run_at should be update with value from run_at.

I don't want to use callbacks. I tried implement attribute `:local_run_at, :time_only, default: -> { :run_at }`, but it is only default value

Could you please show me correct way for Rails do it. Thanks

Comment: You can set it inside your controller.

Comment: I know but I don't want inside controller.

Comment: Another way is to introduce a service class to hide all the logic there.

Comment: The best way to ensure this always occurs is to setup database trigger. Look up database triggers for the database you are using and create a migration that will create this trigger in the database. There are also some gems ([`hairtrigger`](https://github.com/jenseng/hair_trigger) for example) that will offer a cleaner syntax if you prefer (or are going to do this else where)